# Selectabletext from ReadOnly DataGridViewColumn

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` which contains columns which have to be `ReadOnly`.
The problem is, that the value is not selectable... I need to make it possible to copy & paste with the mouse only.

Additionally the `DataGridView.SelectionMode` have to be `DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect`or `DataGridViewSelectionMode.RowHeaderSelect`

Any ideas how to solve this problem ?

I searched for some properties like Editable or something like that, but i only found the `ReadOnly` property.

**EDIT:**

I just need the Cell-Value which is in the ReadOnly cell.

Comment: Readonly is the same as not editable. If you do FullRowSelect it means you will always copy and paste the full row. So what do you want?

Comment: I just need the Cell-Value which is in the ReadOnly cell. I want, that it will be possible for the user to select the whole value or just a substring of it with the mouse.

Comment: You should specify with the mouse in the question... I just added an example that works using ctrl+c

Comment: Will edit it now for mouse

Comment: Made an example of an easy way to copy it with the mouse, the text selection (substring) won't be possible this way tho, as that is edit mode in the datagridview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code I made the columns programmatically and set the 1st column to readonly.  With a selectionmode of `CellSelect` you can copy the readonly data easiest. If you use `FullRowSelect` you always copy the full row (unless you go in edit mode and copy an editable cell).

```
dataGridView.Columns.Add( "column1Column", "T1" );
dataGridView.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;
//The first column (T1) is now ReadOnly
dataGridView.Columns.Add("column2Column", "T2");
dataGridView.Columns.Add("column3Column", "T3");
dataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
//Or use this if you want to copy cell content of readonly cells
dataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect;
```

An easy (in my experience user friendly) way to get data from a ReadOnly cell only using a mouse is create a `CellMouseClick` event handler.

**Example**

```
private void dataGridView_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if ( e.Button == MouseButtons.Right )
        {
            //Set text to clipboard
            Clipboard.SetText( dataGridView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString() );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the clicked cell with `DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect`:

```
DataGridViewCell clickedCell;

private void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
            clickedCell = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
            clickedCell.Selected = true;

            var cellRectangle = dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, true);
            // Show context menu with 'Copy' option
            contextMenuStrip1.Show(dataGridView1, cellRectangle.Left + e.X, cellRectangle.Top + e.Y);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex; 
    }
}
```

Then add a `contextMenuStrip` to the form and in the `copy` item click event (the context menu will be shown from above event):

```
private void copyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    Clipboard.SetText(clickedCell.Value.ToString());
}
```